# Segmentation fault in ~ImageCodecInitializer() while exiting main()

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to implement a median filter(for practice). The program showed the output image correctly but it ended with a segmentation fault. The following error occurred just before exiting main(){}. I.e: After completing each and every line of code in main.

Result of gdb:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff78bf789 in cv::ImageCodecInitializer::~ImageCodecInitializer() ()
from /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.2




 //Code:
 //mainFile.cpp





    #include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.h
     #include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
     #include "lowp.h"
     //#include <stdlib.h>
     using namespace cv;

         void medFilter(Mat &, Mat &, int);

         int main(){
           Mat img = imread("home.jpg",1);
           Mat out;
           medFilter(img,out,7);
           namedWindow("Example");
           imshow("Example", out);
           waitKey(0);
           destroyWindow("Example");
        }

     //lowp.h
        void medFilter(Mat &img, Mat &out, int size){
           Mat low(img.rows, img.cols, img.type());
           int r = img.rows;
           int c = img.cols;
           int hist[256];   
           int w = 0;
           int *win;
           win = new int(size*size);
           for(int h = 0; h<255; h++){
                  hist[h] = 0;
           }
           for(int i = 0; i<r; i++){
                   for(int j = 0; j<c; j++){
                        for(int chi = 0; chi < ch; chi++){
                                  if(i>=size/2 && i<r-size/2 && j>=size/2 && j<c-size/2){
                                           for(int u = -size/2 ; u<=size/2; u++){
                                                 for(int v = -size/2; v<=size/2; v++){
                                                          win[w] = *(img.ptr<uchar>(i + u) + (j + v)*ch + chi);
                                                          w++;
                                                   }
                                           }
                                          w = 0;
                                         *(low.ptr<uchar>(i) + j*ch + chi) = getMedian(win, hist, (size*size));
                                  }else{
                                         *(low.ptr<uchar>(i) + j*ch + chi) = *(img.ptr<uchar>(i) + j*ch + chi);
                                  }
                         }
                 }
          }
          out = low;
  }
  uchar  getMedian(int* w, int* hist, int size){
        uchar h;
        for(int i = 0; i<size; i++){
              hist[w[i]] ++;
         }
          int sum = 0;
          for(h = 0; h<255; h++){
                  sum += hist[h];
                  if(sum>size/2) break;
          }
         for(int i = 0; i<size; i++){
                  hist[w[i]] = 0;
         }
         return h;
  }
```

Comment: You should intent your code in a better way!!

Comment: The crash is happening in ImageCodecInitializer::~ImageCodecInitializer() but I can't see any sign of any objects of that class being created...so the code you've included isn't really going to point to where the problem is.

Comment: @Steephen Intent improved..